# viewing localhost via ip on network binding issues

Tags: apache, apache2, ip, localhost, vhosts

I'm trying to access a site i'm working on via ip, but Im just getting 'it works' which i guess is 127.0.0.1 localhost, I know in IIS i can use binding for this to work but am a bit stumped when it comes to apache on a mac.

Is there a way in hosts or httpd-vhosts.conf to bind the ip of the machine to a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, site had to be the first vhost in httpd-vhosts.conf so it would be default